# Windows 7 won't update

Tags: windows-7, windows-update, updates, services

My problem is that Windows 7 won't update - legal MSDN copy.
It says: "the update service is not started", and if I start it, it immediately shuts itself down. In the event viewer is nothing interesting to see, no fatals and no warnings, only start/stop events.
I've got no clue from where to start looking, so here's an Hijackthis log:

```
Logfile of Trend Micro HijackThis v2.0.3 (BETA)
Scan saved at 18:34:05, on 7/02/2010
Platform: Unknown Windows (WinNT 6.01.3504)
MSIE: Internet Explorer v8.00 (8.00.7600.16385)
Boot mode: Normal

Running processes:
C:\Windows\system32\taskhost.exe
C:\Windows\system32\Dwm.exe
C:\Windows\Explorer.EXE
C:\Windows\PLFSetI.exe
C:\Program Files\VMware\VMware Player\hqtray.exe
C:\Program Files\Avira\AntiVir Desktop\avgnt.exe
C:\Program Files\Windows Live\Messenger\msnmsgr.exe
C:\Program Files\Windows Sidebar\sidebar.exe
C:\Program Files\Windows Live\Contacts\wlcomm.exe
C:\Program Files\Skype\Phone\Skype.exe
C:\Program Files\Skype\Plugin Manager\skypePM.exe
C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe
C:\Program Files\TrendMicro\HiJackThis\HiJackThis.exe

R1 - HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main,Search Page = http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=54896
R0 - HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main,Start Page = http://www.google.be/
R1 - HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main,Default_Page_URL = http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=69157
R1 - HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main,Default_Search_URL = http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=54896
R1 - HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main,Search Page = http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=54896
R0 - HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main,Start Page = http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=69157
R0 - HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Search,SearchAssistant = 
R0 - HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Search,CustomizeSearch = 
R1 - HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings,ProxyOverride = *.local
R0 - HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Toolbar,LinksFolderName = 
O2 - BHO: AcroIEHelperStub - {18DF081C-E8AD-4283-A596-FA578C2EBDC3} - C:\Program Files\Common Files\Adobe\Acrobat\ActiveX\AcroIEHelperShim.dll
O2 - BHO: (no name) - {5C255C8A-E604-49b4-9D64-90988571CECB} - (no file)
O2 - BHO: Groove GFS Browser Helper - {72853161-30C5-4D22-B7F9-0BBC1D38A37E} - C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office12\GrooveShellExtensions.dll
O2 - BHO: Windows Live ID Sign-in Helper - {9030D464-4C02-4ABF-8ECC-5164760863C6} - C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live\WindowsLiveLogin.dll
O4 - HKLM\..\Run: [PLFSetL] C:\Windows\\PLFSetL.exe
O4 - HKLM\..\Run: [PLFSetI] C:\Windows\PLFSetI.exe
O4 - HKLM\..\Run: [VMware hqtray] "C:\Program Files\VMware\VMware Player\hqtray.exe"
O4 - HKLM\..\Run: [avgnt] "C:\Program Files\Avira\AntiVir Desktop\avgnt.exe" /min
O4 - HKCU\..\Run: [msnmsgr] "C:\Program Files\Windows Live\Messenger\msnmsgr.exe" /background
O4 - HKCU\..\Run: [Sidebar] C:\Program Files\Windows Sidebar\sidebar.exe /autoRun
O4 - HKUS\S-1-5-19\..\Run: [Sidebar] %ProgramFiles%\Windows Sidebar\Sidebar.exe /autoRun (User 'LOCAL SERVICE')
O4 - HKUS\S-1-5-19\..\RunOnce: [mctadmin] C:\Windows\System32\mctadmin.exe (User 'LOCAL SERVICE')
O4 - HKUS\S-1-5-20\..\Run: [Sidebar] %ProgramFiles%\Windows Sidebar\Sidebar.exe /autoRun (User 'NETWORK SERVICE')
O4 - HKUS\S-1-5-20\..\RunOnce: [mctadmin] C:\Windows\System32\mctadmin.exe (User 'NETWORK SERVICE')
O8 - Extra context menu item: E&xporteren naar Microsoft Excel - res://C:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~2\Office12\EXCEL.EXE/3000
O9 - Extra button: Verzenden naar OneNote - {2670000A-7350-4f3c-8081-5663EE0C6C49} - C:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~2\Office12\ONBttnIE.dll
O9 - Extra 'Tools' menuitem: Verz&enden naar
```

Comment: +1 interesting question, never seen that before. Usually windows update is very in-your-face, rebooting you at inopportune times :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running this

[Repair & Fix Windows Updates with Fix WU Utility](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/repair-fix-windows-updates-with-fix-wu-utility)

Answer (score 1):

The following is from Microsoft. The 1st solution fixed my problem:

> From the case log, I understand that the error code 80072EFE was
>   received when trying to perform Windows Update. If there has been any
>   misunderstanding, please let me know.   I fully understand the
>   inconvenience you have experienced. We will work together to resolve
>   this issue through the course of the case.   This issue can be caused
>   by one of the following factors:
>
> 1. The computer was attacked by viruses.
> 2. Some background programs, such as antivirus programs or firewalls (especially CA Firewall), block access to the Windows Update site.
> 3. Incorrect DNS Settings.   We will address some of the more common causes of this issue. It is important that we attempt to connect to
>      the Windows Update web site after each step to confirm whether the
>      resolution has worked. This will prevent us from having to proceed
>      with additional troubleshooting steps and provide us with valuable
>      feedback to further develop our support resolutions for you and our
>      future customers. Your assistance is greatly appreciated.
>
> ## Suggestion 1: Run the tool to clear spyware
>
> 1. Download the file [TDSSKiller.zip](http://support.kaspersky.com/downloads/utils/tdsskiller.zip) from the following link and save it on the Desktop.
> 2. Double click TDSSKiller.zip to unzip the file.
> 3. Double click TDSSKiller.exe to scan the system.
> 4. Wait for the scan and disinfection process to complete.   Please Note: The third-party product discussed here is manufactured by a
>      company that is independent of Microsoft. We make no warranty, implied
>      or otherwise, regarding this product's performance or reliability.
>      Now try Windows Update to see if the issue has been resolved. Please
>      let us know if this step has resolved it. If not, please proceed to
>      the next step.
>
> ## Suggestion 2: Reset DNS Settings
>
> 1. Click "Start", input "NCPA.CPL" (without quotation marks) to Start Search bar and press "Enter".
> 2. Right-click the network connection and click "Properties".    If you are prompted for an administrator password or confirmation, type
>      the password or provide confirmation.
> 3. Click to highlight "Internet Protocol Version 6 (TCP/IPv6)" and click "Properties".
> 4. Check "Obtain an IP address automatically" and "Obtain DNS server address automatically".
> 5. Click "OK".
> 6. Click to highlight "Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4)" and click "Properties".
> 7. Check "Obtain an IP address automatically" and "Obtain DNS server address automatically".
> 8. Click "OK".
> 9. Reboot the computer.   Now try Windows Update again to check if the issue has been resolved. If not, please proceed to the next step.
>      Suggestion 3: Disable firewalls or other Internet browser programs
>      that can affect the Internet connection
>
> This issue could be caused by third party applications. Let's first
>   try disabling or uninstalling any third party security applications
>   you may have installed on the computer. Please be advised that this is
>   for troubleshooting purposes only.
>
> Once we have resolved the issue,
>   the applications should be re-enabled or reinstalled immediately. If
>   the third party security application is determined to be the cause,
>   please contact the vendor for assistance.   You may have a different
>   security application not listed below that could also be causing the
>   issue. Even if the firewall has been running for some time without any
>   problems, new updates may create issues.
>
> Here is a list of the most
>   common security applications:
>
> - Symantec
> - Norton
> - McAfee
> - Zone Alarm
> - Panda Security
> - Kaspersky
> - Sophos Antivirus
> - Comodo Firewall
> - AntispamSniper
> - Webroot
> - Spy Sweeper
> - Accelerator
> - Spybot
>
> Once the third
>   party security applications have been disabled or removed, please
>   access the Windows Update web site again. If you encounter problems
>   disabling these programs, we recommend completely uninstalling them
>   while troubleshooting.
>
> Before uninstalling any application, please
>   enable your Windows Firewall and ensure that you have the CDs or files
>   needed to re-install the program.

Answer (score 0):

With windows 10, Microsoft has been trying to "bully" other users to upgrade to 10. One form that this has taken has been to given Windows 7 machines low priority on their update servers. And I mean *really* low priority. Also, some updates seemed to turn off updates for who-knows-why if later updates weren't also done at the same time.

This worked for me...

```
net stop http /y
net stop wuauserv 
regsvr32 %windir%\system32\wups2.dll 
net start wuauserv
```

Then, and this is highly important...

Start windows update, and if it seems to hang...

Let it run for literally 24 hours straight. It literally can take a full day for it to actually get around to downloading updates due to the ridiculoiusly low priority. I can download a Windows 7 SP1 install disk image from a African server using dial-up faster than I can download the updates from 7 to 7SP1 from Microsoft whose corporate campus is literally a 45 minute drive from my house. They're bottlenecking it that much.